# How to prove the recurrence relation for this generating function problem?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

I am a software engineer and I am learning combinatorics theory on my own. I recently got stumped by the following problem.

### Problem

Let $a_{0} = 2$ where  $a_{n} = 3a_{n-1} - 2$ with $n>0$. Given $G(x) = \sum_1^na_{k}x^k $ be the generating function. Prove $G(x) = \frac{2-4x}{(1-3)(1-x)}$

### Attempt

Let us begin with $a_k = 3a_{k-1} -2 $ so that we can see $a_k x^k = 3a_{k-1}x^k -2x^k$. Next we note $\sum_0^na_{k}x^k = \sum_0^k3a_{k-1}x^k -\sum_0^k2x^k $. Simplifying further, we obtain $G(x) = 3xG(x)-\sum_0^k2x^k$. Thus, we have $G(x)(1-3x) = -\sum_0^k2x^k$

### Huh?

How can $-\sum_0^k2x^k = \frac{2-4x}{(1-x)}$? I dare sare I have made an error in my approach above, but I cannot see it. I feel like I got so close to solving this, but completely missed the boat. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with both upper and lower index. Let $G(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n$ then you recurrence says
$$
\begin{split}
G(x)
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k \\
 &= a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty 3 a_{k-1} x^k - \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2 x^k \\
 &= 2 + 3x \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k-1} x^{k-1} - 2 \left[\frac{1}{1-x} - 1\right] \\
 &= 4 + 3x \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k - \frac{2}{1-x} \\
 &= 4 + 3x G(x) - \frac{2}{1-x}
\end{split}
$$
so you end up with
$$
G(x) = 4 + 3x G(x) - \frac{2}{1-x}
$$
which you can now solve for $G(x)$

Comment: Why is your summation become $\frac{1}{1-x} -1$ I am sorry. I don't see this sir.

Comment: Based on identities shouldn't $\sum_1^\infty2x^k = \frac{2x}{1-x}$?

Comment: It is, and it works out even better with that expression.

Comment: @hlyates Leaving out the factor of $2$, note that
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} - 1 = \frac{x}{1-x}...
$$
The logic is simple
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k - x^0 = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1
$$